# check hex string contains only hex bounded values

Tags: java, string, hex

How to check a given hex string contains only hex number. is there is any simple method or any java library for the same?i have string like "01AF" and i have to check string only contains hex range values,for that what i am doing now is take the string and then split the string and then converted it to appropriate format then make a check for that value.is there is any simple method for that?

Comment: Could you provide an example of input and expected results? Are there any limitations like string length? I suspect that `matches(regex)` can help.

Comment: You should have a look at String.matches with a regexp checking interval 0-9A-F. This article can help you : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @Pshemo "O1AG"...this will show an error becouse of the occurence of 'G' in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
{
    String hex = "AAA"
    int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);  
    System.out.println("valid hex);
 }
 catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
 {
    // not a valid hex
    System.out.println("not a valid hex);
 }
```

This will throw NumberFormatException if the hex string is invalid.

Refer the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if string contains only 0-9, a-h or A-H you can try using

```
yourString.matches("[0-9a-fA-F]+");
```

---

To optimize it you can earlier create `Pattern`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F]+");
```

and later reuse it as

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourData);
if (m.matches())
```

and even reuse `Matcher` instance with

```
m.reset(newString);
if (m.matches())
```

Comment: Hex numbers only go up to F, not H :)

Comment: @Julien Woops, wrong side of `g` key :) Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Given `String str` as your input string:**

Option #1:

```
public static boolean isHex(String str)
{
    try
    {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(str,16);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Option #2:

```
private static boolean[] hash = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
static // Runs once
{
    for (int i=0; i<hash.length; i++)
        hash[i] = false;
    for (char c : "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef".toCharArray())
        hash[c] = true;
}
public static boolean isHex(String str)
{
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        if (!hash[c])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Option #2 is really ugly.

Comment: @Julien: what about option #3?

Comment: Hum, I would suggest to replace option #2 with something like String.matches("[1-9a-fA-F]+") (I'm not really sure of the regexp syntax but it should not be far).

Comment: Option #2 and #3 are awful because of the for loop in fact :) It adds +1 to code complexity and is really slower than any method using regexp.

Comment: @Julien, I replaced them with a slightly "prettier" implementation. However, please note that in **all cases** (including my first option, and including your "regex" suggestion), the complexity depends on the length of the input string. In my previous options 2 and 3, the complexity would be slightly higher if the input string was shorter than 22 characters (all possible hex digits). But the difference is pretty minor, and in general, this question doesn't look like a complexity-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reached this thread trying to avoid the following exception when parsing a Mongodb ObjectId:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [anInvalidId]
```

Then note [this utility method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#isValid-java.lang.String-) offered by the mongo-java-driver library:

```
ObjectId.isValid(stringId)
```

Related thread:

[How to determine if a string can be used as a MongoDB ObjectID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132675/how-to-determine-if-a-string-can-be-used-as-a-mongodb-objectid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch expression:

```
public static boolean isHex(final String str) {
    return str != null && 
           !str.isEmpty() && 
           str.codePoints()
              .allMatch((final int codePoint) -> switch (codePoint) {
            case '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 
                 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' -> true;
            default -> false;
    });
}
```

This solution is more efficient than using a regular expression and it doesn't rely on a try catch.