# How to determine if a string can be used as a MongoDB ObjectID?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, micronaut-data

I am using Micronaut framework with JAVA and trying to validate the objectId with the below string.

```
60236833af6a1d49478d2bef   // Valid mongo ObjectId

60236833a46a1d49478d2bef  // Invalid mongo ObjectId
```

How can I perform either the string has valid objectId or not in Java with MongoDb?

Comment: Please note the above two strings are valid hexadecimal string representations. Both are valid strings and can be used to construct a `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

if(ObjectId.isValid(value)){
}
```

Comment: The `value` is hexString - a potential ObjectId as a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [ObjectId specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/objectid.rst) for how they are generated.

Any 24-character hexadecimal string should be convertable to an ObjectId.